# what should be difference between dev and prod wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am working on java web services using the axis2. Initially, I received the dev WSDL URL and I generated the web service client code and called the required web service. Now I have received the prod WSDL URL. I have below concerns
1. Do I need to generate the web service client code again with prod WSDL URL.
2. or In my existing code I just need to modify the end point url to prod.
3. are the class names and functionality remains same if I generate the java code using either dev or prod WSDL URLs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is if the DEV and PROD WSDLs are the same.

If they deployed their WSDL without changes from DEV to PROD, 
then you don't need to regenerate your classes, I am pretty sure.

So you can just point your code to the PROD endpoint.

But if the PROD WSDL is different from the one in DEV
(which should not be the case normally once they did
a DEV to PROD release of their WSDL), then you will need
to regenerate your client-side classes.

Basically if the one managing the WS changes something
significant (e.g. adds parameter somewhere) in their 
PROD environment you also need to change client code in 
your PROD environment (for the two systems to stay in sync).

That's what I know based on my experience.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs.